# EXTJS grid store load - adding parameters?

Tags: web-services, extjs, parameter-passing

I'm in the process on converting an asp repeater into an EXTJS grid. Above the repeater is a dropdown and a radiobutton list. The dropdown selects which clients' data the repeater shows, and the radiobuttonlist selects the query type (default, resource, or role). Currently, when the ddl or radiobutton is changed, the page postsback with the new data.

I'm not sure how to pass the value of these two objects into my static webservice on the backend via the extjs store api GET call.

The extjs store code...

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoSync: false,
                    model: 'Assembly',
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        headers: { "Content-Type": 'application/json' },
                        api: {
                            read: '/Admin/BillRateData.aspx/Get'
                        },
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: function (o) {
                                if (o.d) {
                                    return o.d;
                                } else {
                                    return o.children;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        writer: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'jsonData',
                            encode: false,
                            allowSingle: false
                        },
                        listeners: {
                            exception: function (proxy, response, operation) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                    title: "Workflow Groups Error",
                                    msg: operation.action + ' Operation Failed: ' + operation.getError().statusText,
                                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And the webservice...(with some psuedocode)

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static List<BillRate> Get()
    {
        using (TimEntities db = new TimEntities())
        {
            int tableId = Int32.Parse(ddlTable.SelectedValue);

            var defaultQry = from t1 in db.BillCostTableDatas
                             where t1.TableId == tableId
                             && t1.ResourceId == 0 && t1.RoleId == 0
                             orderby t1.Rate
                             select new
                             {
                                 id = t1.Id,
                                 resource = "",
                                 role = "",
                                 rate = t1.Rate,
                                 TierName = ""
                             };

            var resourceQry = from t1 in db.BillCostTableDatas
                              join t2 in db.Machines on t1.ResourceId equals t2.Machine_ID
                              join t3 in db.TOMIS_USER on t2.Machine_User_ID equals t3.User_ID
                              join t4 in db.PricingTierNames on t1.PricingTierID equals t4.TierID
                              where t1.TableId == tableId
                                && t1.ResourceId != 0
                                && t1.RoleId == 0
                              orderby t3.LName, t3.FName, t1.Rate, t4.TierName
                              select new
                              {
                                  id = t1.Id,
                                  resource = t3.LName + ", " + t3.FName,
                                  role = "",
                                  rate = t1.Rate,
                                  TierName = t4.TierName
                              };

            var roleQry = from t1 in db.BillCostTableDatas
                          join t2 in db.TaskRoles on t1.RoleId equals t2.Id
                          where t1.TableId == tableId
                          && t1.ResourceId == 2 && t1.RoleId != 0
                          orderby t2.Name, t1.Rate
                          select new
                          {
                              id = t1.Id,
                              resource = "",
                              role = t2.Name,
                              rate = t1.Rate,
                              TierName = ""
                          };

            if (this.rblOptions.SelectedValue == "resource")
            {
                var results = from Res in resourceQry.ToList()
                              select new BillRate
                              {

                              };
                return results.ToList();
            }
            else if (this.rblOptions.SelectedValue == "role")
            {
                var results = from Res in roleQry.ToList()
                              select new BillRate
                              {

                              };
                return results.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                var results = from Res in defaultQry.ToList()
                              select new BillRate
                              {

                              };
                return results.ToList();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking. How to send the params to the server using Ext store?

Comment: The grid gets filled with the js "read: '/Admin/BillRateData.aspx/Get'", which calls the webmethod I pasted. What I'm trying to figure out, is how to add parameters to the GET call with values of the dropdown and radiobutton list, so that the webmethod can know what query to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you trigger your store loading manually, you can pass the [`params`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-cfg-params) options to the [`load` method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load).

Example:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    // prevent the store from loading before we told it to do so
    autoLoad: false
    ...
});

store.load({
    params: {clientId: 123, queryType: 'default'}
    ...
});
```

If you want the params to be sent for multiple subsequent queries, you can write them in the [`extraParams`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-extraParams) property of the proxy.

Example:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { ... });

Ext.apply(store.getProxy().extraParams, {
    clientId: 321
    ,queryType: 'role'
});

// the store will still need a refresh
store.reload();
```

The way these params are passed to the server will depend on the type of request. For GET ones, they will be appended as query params; for POST they will be embedded in the request body.